# Ajax POST Data for certain field id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to send some data to an ajax script, usually I create a form tag and give the form an id like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
```

And then I just add the following in the ajax:

```
data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
```

This sends all the form data from my form. However, this time I am trying to run it without the form tag and instead i have two fields with unique id's like this:

```
<input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name">
<input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name">
```

I want to send the data from these two fields only. So i've put the following code in:

```
data: $("#first-name,#last-name"),
```

It does seem to work, but wondering if this is the correct and compatible way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send data as a serialized string: data: `$("#first-name,#last-name").serialize()`;

Answer (score 1):

You should also use [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function like

```
$("#first-name,#last-name").serialize()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j2zn76o4/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can create the object on the fly, like this:

```
...
data: { 
     'first_name': $('#first_name').val(),
     'last_name': $('#last_name').val()
},
...
```

`$.ajax()` can convert data automatically if not already a string, that's why you shouldn't use `serialize()` here.

Comment: is this method a better option than the suggested $("#first-name,#last-name").serialize() method?

Comment: It's a matter of choice... That way you have control of `key` that will be submitted to server, e.g. your input can have one name and you can send completely different name to server.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

> data
>   Type: PlainObject or String
>   A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

In this case, I think you may use `PlainObject` as **unixarmy** and **psylogic** said.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use serialize. You can call the fields by posting the datas

```
data : {
first_name: $('#first-name').val(),
last_name: $('#last-name').val(),
},
```

I hope this helps :)